# I created a report and I see all fields but users with other profiles than me (I have System Admin) don't see those fields, even though I added

Tags: reporting, custom-reports

"read access" fields to their profiles.

What else should I do so that they could see all fields from report?

Answer (score 0):

Check the following:

- FLS on each field
- Check that fields are indeed part of the custom report time -- I presume so
- Might sound silly, but check that the user is creating the right report